# Does the part of speech of "said" differ between dialects?

Tags: adjectives, dialects, parts-of-speech, determiners

*Note:* This is similar to, but not a duplicate of, [an old question on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/can-the-word-said-be-a-determiner-in-written-english).

Consider these two sentences:

1. One employee accused him of serious crimes, but **said employee** did not provide any specifics.
2. One employee accused him of serious crimes, but **the said employee** did not provide any specifics.

At least to me, (1) sounds fine, but (2) sounds, at least, quite unidiomatic. It seems that we should classify *said* as a determinative (or determiner, depending on your terminology), rather than as a (participial) adjective, at least in sentences like (1), where it appears with a singular count noun that lacks any other determiner. If we accept sentences like (2), we would conclude that it can be either a determinative or an adjective; if we reject sentences like (2), we would conclude that it can only be a determinative.

There was a question about this earlier on [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/can-the-word-said-be-a-determiner-in-written-english) where the accepted answer maintained that *said* is, nevertheless, an adjective in both cases, and that a noun phrase like *said employee* is simply a case of an NP lacking a determiner, as can occur in certain registers. But *said* seems to be used much more widely than other adjectives in this way, regardless of register; I think most would find (1) acceptable in any context, and [a Google search for "but said person was"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22but+said+person+was%22) turns up many thousands of results.

One comment may have clarified things. Ngrams seems to suggest that *said* is typically used without a determiner [in American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+the+said+person+was%2Cthat+said+person+was&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10), but with a determiner [in British English.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+the+said+person+was%2Cthat+said+person+was&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10) Note that Ngrams tends to underestimate differences between dialects due to texts getting misclassified.

So: is this hypothesis correct? Should we say that *said* can be a determinative in American English, but not in British English?

**Edit:** Some of the commenters were saying that this is just legalese, or business-speak, or limited to formal contexts. So I present some attestations from various sources and registers:

- From [The New York Times:](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/15/opinion/trump-american-values.html) "More likely, however, you’re suggesting that said person is willfully ignorant"
- From [/r/AmITheAsshole:](https://www.reddit.com/r/AmItheAsshole/comments/16q88jc/aita_for_laying_boundaries_to_my_coworker/) "and said coworker is now upset even though I’ve verbalized my boundaries before."
- From [a recent romance novel:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trouble_in_Blue/1848EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22but+said+person+was%22&pg=PT12&printsec=frontcover) "But said person was anticipating mid-to-late September, not early June."
- From a ["romantic comedy" book:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Never_Ever_Getting_Back_Together/_gfXEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) "Yeah, well, said boyfriend is probably developing some trust issues of his own"
- From [Tumblr:](https://www.tumblr.com/madlori/158966677765/funny-story-so-i-made-a-valentine-for-a-friend-a) "I made a valentine for a friend a while ago and said friend posted it on twitter"
- From [Wattpad fanfiction:](https://www.wattpad.com/12415609-a-warm-winter-%7Ejohn-lock%7E-chapter-1-the-breakup) "He and said partner are happy, but is this happiness nothing but a lie?"
- From [another Reddit comment:](https://www.reddit.com/r/stories/comments/17bxffi/my_bestfriend_and_boyfriend_have_a_secret_that_i/) "Girl the reason he is not mad is he and said Bff hooked up and you and he are now even."

Comment: _Said_ without determiner doesn't sound unidiomatic to me (as a BrE speaker), but I can't find evidence for this view.

Comment: @KateBunting Sounds fine to this AmE speaker, as well.

Comment: I think your Ngram has too few results to be statistically significant.

Comment: @user888379 Sounds strange to this AmE speaker. However, I find the "said" determiner strange in general -- I've mostly only seen it used in patents.

Comment: @Barmar It's not a determiner; to paraphrase the OED, it's merely the case that here, as with *same*, certain forms of abbreviated communications including business and law may on occasion dispense with same. Code phrase: *“usually with* the”.

Comment: I don't think BrE and AmE are dialects. Apart from that, "said" means the same thing on both sides of the pond. (2) does sound unidiomatic in both in fact it is idiomatic. However, in (2), it's the said employee as it refers to him. The lack of a determiner comes from *modern legalese*. Take a look at the Habeas Corpus Act of 1679, the determiner the is all over the place with the said writ and the said officer. etc. It's a hoot to read: https://statutes.org.uk/site/the-statutes/seventeenth-century/1679-31-ch-2-c-2-habeas-corpus-act/

Comment: @tchrist I think the OED is just wrong on this point. Looking it up online, it seems to be ubiquitous: you can find it in forum posts, news articles, advice columns, fiction and nonfiction books, reviews, etc. To me (1) seems correct regardless of register, and I seem to be in good company in that judgment. I wouldn't make the same claim about *same,* where it is certainly true that the use without a determiner is restricted to certain contexts/registers/idioms.

Comment: And in this other act of Parliament of 1649 (An Act for discharging Poor Prisoners unable to satisfie their Creditors) [haha], said is preceded by the everywhere: the said prisoner, the said oath. https://www.british-history.ac.uk/no-series/acts-ordinances-interregnum/pp240-241 Maybe by and by I shall make this an answer. Please don't jump the gun on me.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not asking about its meaning, or about the history of its use, but about its syntactic function and part of speech in contemporary, non-legalese English.

Comment: I know you know the meaning but you were asking about the determiner. And I am saying that  it *comes from legal English*, way back, and with the determiner the, historically. Afaik, "said" in not much used in texts that are 100% devoid of a legal tone. In your employee accusation example, the text is legalistic or about to become so, right? Whether or not you have "the", "said" is an adjective derived from a past participle. What else could it be?

Comment: Use of _said_ without _the_ in this way could just be classed as an extragrammatical idiom. One despairs of the finanglings some undertake to make usages conform to their analyses.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Said stands for this or that or the: ‘Said’ and ‘Such’ – the use of said or such is archaic and awkward and can be easily replaced with the, this or that. For example, the agreement reads so much more easily than said agreement. //As such, it would be a determiner. Though for me, it is adjectival.  From: We Promise to Deliver You From Gobbledygook, a UK legal site: https://www.mincoffs.co.uk/latest/promise-deliver-gobbledygook/ extragrammatical idiom, pshaw. [sigh]

Comment: Last comment: others call it a demonstrative: which is in line with the preceding: this or that.

Comment: @Lambie The determiner? / adjective? divide (for sentence [1]) illustrates that 'unusual usage' (ie 'idiom') is appropriate while often hidebound academics battle using favourite constituency tests.

Comment: This seems to fit the pattern of a "false title": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title

Comment: @Greybeard Somewhat, but aren't those always NPs used as attributive appositives? We skip determiners before adjectives all the time, but somehow I don’t recall anybody ever proclaiming that doing so automatically (pre-)determinativates them: *“I scared away both the coyotes **last** time but one.”* :)

Comment: @tchrist - I agree. Yours is the adverbial use of an NP. "Said man" is not adverbial - the lack of a determiner is supported as a subject and object later in the article, although not every one agrees.

Answer (score 5):

Relevant discussion of *said* in [New members of ‘closed classes’ in English](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/ClosedClasses.pdf) (B. Reynolds and GKP) with *the said district* as an example. (See link to read more)

> 2.2.1 Said
>
> The word *said* follows a slightly different trajectory. It spread from past participle to
> adjective to determinative only to gradually fade out of use, today persisting mostly in
> legal documents. Our basis for categorizing *said* as a determinative is that singular,
> countable nouns like *district* normally require a determiner, and adjectives cannot
> perform this function (e.g., **it was in good district*). The adjective and the determinative
> are illustrated in figure 7.

According to their analysis, *the said + N*, ***said*** is an adjective (not a determinative) since it appears with *the*. But *said + N*, ***said*** is a determinative.

No comment on the difference between American and British dialects.

Comment: Thanks for turning this up--given its authorship by GKP himself, this is as close to an official answer as we're going to get, as far as H&P's classification is concerned.  But I find his view that this "persists mostly in legal documents" at odds with the numerous attestations from highly informal contexts listed in my question

Comment: Yes, as I said in my comments. Yes, mostly in legal documents or ones with a *legal tone*. The employee in the OP's is about to be clobbered criminally, it would seem.

Comment: Cheers. Saved me a post! +1

Comment: @Araucaria-Him I thought you would beat me to it for a better elaboration!

Comment: @Lambie See the edit at the end of my question regarding attestations outside of legal context and in places where the tone is clearly not a legal one.

Comment: @alphabet That Reddit thing is just someone using it. Those uses are colloquial borrowings.

Comment: @alphabet MWDEU (concise version) comments: "Such usage still occurs, but the legalistic connotations of said have long been so familiar that those who employ it in other contexts typically do so for deliberate effect, often humorous."

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Interesting! But maybe because "other" has still "limited development" (according to the paper)  as a determinative that's why they stick to the adjective categorization for "said" to mean "aforementioned" mentioned by BillJ in "the said NP"? If I'm not mistaken CGEL classifies "other" as a common noun or an adjective functioning as a modifier.

Comment: @user424874 +1 Yes, I think you're right, having had a look at CGEL again. It seems I've been having an errant mental episode. My memory's been making up its own entries :-/

Answer (score 4):

There is little evidence for *said* as an adjective as it fails the tests: no predicative uses (**the person was/seemed said*), no modification by adverbs (**the exactly/recently said person*), no gradation, and no -*ly* alternation with a corresponding adverb.

The only commonality it has with adjectives is that it appears in a pre-head position in noun phrases. Note that even in pre-head modifier position, it still has to precede all others: its properties are similar to determinative *one*, which can act as a determiner or as pre-head modifier (*One reason was given / The one reason was given*).

As to the British-American divide...

Out of 81 hits for *said person* in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, only one has determiner *the* before *said*, the others having no determiner at all; 27 of 127 in the Supreme Court corpus do.

The data in the HANSARD courpus (British Parliament) differ starkly with only two out of 118 hits lacking determiner *the* before *said*.

In the more balanced News on the Web corpus, 860 of 1111 hits have *the* before *said*. The ones without include some hits from British English sources.

> We aim to share info and set up a collection to get funds to offer a
> reward to anyone who can help bring this person to justice, securing
> arrest and conviction of ***said person***. ([Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-6702781/Fears-cat-killer-loose-Devon-six-pets-die-street.html))

Generally, these data do uphold the British-American divide on the use of *said*, though they do not rule out either of the uses for one group or the other.

Interestingly, it's excessively rare that a determiner other than *the* appears before *said*, and it's similarly rare to find anything between *the* and *said* which seems to argue for *the said* as being a sort of idiom of a determiner.

In sum, seeing as it ***can*** play the part of a determiner in a noun phrase headed by a singular count noun for at least some speakers of both varieties, and lacking any strong evidence for *said* as an adjective, it would be best classed as a determinative on both sides of the pond.

Comment: How is this any different from something like *aforementioned* in *the **aforementioned** young lady*?

Comment: @tchrist  For one thing, _said_ is much more common without _the_  than _aforementioned_ is: 9 hits for _of **aforementioned** SINGULAR NOUN_ vs 576 hits for _of **said** SINGULAR NOUN_ in the Corpus of Contemporary American English. This makes it much easier to class as common usage and not just legal short-hand. Besides this, _aforementioned_ can be modified by adverbs like  _previously_, _briefly_. However, there may well also be a case for _aforementioned_ as a determinative!

Comment: I don't see how the word said in "the said employee" can be a determiner/native because that would mean you have **two determiners** together. Now what?

Comment: I take "said" to be an adjective meaning "aforementioned", The determiner "the" seems to be optional, at least it is in BrE.

Comment: @Lambie Two determinatives, only one of which is acting as a determiner. Determinative would be the part of speech, and determiner the function. Not all determinatives are mutually exclusive _this_ and _many_ for example.

Comment: @BillJ The evidence seems to say otherwise.

Comment: @BillJ As the other answer says, a paper coauthored by GKP himself claims it has become a determinative.

Comment: @DW256 Most determinatives express quantification, but I wouldn't say that "said" does. And the fact that it can be replaced by the adjective "aforementioned" seems telling. I value Huddleston's opinion somewhat over Pullum's and most definitely over Reynolds.

Comment: Here's some entries for ["*This said person*"](http://tinyurl.com/c6eaf87u). I think that being *said* means that the NP's got to be definite, but this does not preclude, for example, demonstratives. Here's ["*My said enemy*"](http://tinyurl.com/y68xwtrz), which of course is definite too.